# How to use select with stdout?

Tags: c, select, stdout

I have the following code

```
    fd_set          set;
    struct          timeval timeout;
    printf("first printf\n"); // displayed
    FD_ZERO(&set);
    timeout.tv_sec = 1;

    FD_SET(fileno(stdout), &set);
    if (select(FD_SETSIZE, NULL, &set, NULL, &timeout)!=1)
    {
        stdout_closed = true;
        return;
    }
    printf("second printf\n"); // Not displayed
```

I m trying to check the ability to write to the stdout before `printf("second printf\n");`. but with this code, the select return a value `!= 1` and then the printf remain unreacheable. it looks like the select return "*not possible*" to write to the stdout.

Could you explain this behavior?

Comment: Two things: You don't clear `timeout.tv_usec`; and the first argument to `select` should be the highest descriptor plus one (so `fileno(stdout) + 1`). Also remember that `select` can return `-1` for errors, you need to check for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call to select() is returning -1, and errno is 22 (invalid argument) because you've got junk values in the timeout.  Try this:

```
FD_ZERO(&set);
timeout.tv_sec = 1;
timeout.tv_usec = 0; /* ADD THIS LINE to initialize tv_usec to 0 so it's valid */
```

and it should work.